# how to get from row col notation to A1 notation in xlsxwriter add_series()

Tags: python, charts, data-visualization, xlsxwriter

I'm not clueless on how to convert row col to A1 notation and use it in `add_series()` method for charts in XlsxWriter.

Please find below code for reference :

```
 print "Drawing Simultaneous Busy Cores"
    writer.targetWrite('simultaneous_busy_cores', 'weighted_average', *write_data)
    row = writer.getRow('simultaneous_busy_cores')
    str1_cat = xl_rowcol_to_cell(6, 1, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
    str2_cat = xl_rowcol_to_cell(6, 8, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
    str1_val = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row-1, 1, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
    str2_val = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row-1, 8, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
    print str1_cat
    print str2_cat
    print str1_val
    print str2_val
    dict_series = {
             'name':       'simultaneous_busy_cores',
             'categories': '=simultaneous_busy_cores!str1_cat:str2_cat',
             'values':     '=simultaneous_busy_cores!str1_val:str2_val',
             'data_labels': {'percentage': True, }
             }
    chart1.add_series(dict_series)
    chart1.set_title({'name': 'simultaneous_busy_cores'})
    chart1.set_style(10)
    target_sheet.insert_chart('K2', chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})
```

Values for str_cat and str_val are :

```
Drawing Simultaneous Busy Cores
$B$7
$I$7
$B$24
$I$24
```

Any help is appreciated TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the direct question, you could use `string.format()` or `%` to insert the variable values into the string:

```
'=simultaneous_busy_cores!%s:%s' % (str1_cat, str2_cat),
```

However, that is more work than is necessary since XlsxWriter already supports a list syntax for categories and values:

```
dict_series = {
    'name':       'simultaneous_busy_cores',
    'categories': ['simultaneous_busy_cores', 6, 1, 6, 8],
    'values':     ['simultaneous_busy_cores', row-1, 1, row-1],
    'data_labels': {'percentage': True, }
}
```

See the documentation on [`add_series()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @John that worked like a charm!  I wasn't aware that list assumes the entire range of rows and columns, when we provide first and last values.